# Identify adjective and adverb

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

"My older brother has always done his job well" !

Comment: You tell us what you think first.

Comment: Always and well are adverb ! If I'm not wrong

Comment: An adjective describes an object; an adverb describes an action (how it is done). This question is more suited to [ELL.SE], although even they will want a bit more effort expended, I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adverb: `well`, `always`

'`Well`' and '`always`' tells you in what manner the job is **done**(verb).

Adjective: `older`

'`Older`' describes your **brother**(a noun).

Comment: The downvote is for answering a question so obviously off-topic, not the answer. As Andrew Leach has said, the sister site for more basic questions would not consider it a suitable question either. Giving an answer here encourages further unsuitable questions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth would it be appropriate to delete the answer?